# Adding settings button in UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I am trying to add a settings Button in my Navigation Controller, so i have in viewDidLoad()
My code bellow is not the full code since stackoverflow wouldn't let me paste it all, but i think all the relevant informations are below. With this code the settings button is not showing on my simulator.
'''
class NewTabBar: UITabBarController {

```
var transparentView = UIView()
var cellId = "Cell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //TableView
    slideView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    
    self.view.addSubview(middleButton)
    view.addSubview(slideView) // ova e fioka view-to ;)
    
    slideView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    slideView.backgroundColor = .white
    slideView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    
    self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Submit"
    self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    
    let homeTabBarItem = generateNavController(vc: ProfileController(), title: "Home", image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "home"))
    let scheduleVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScheduleTableViewController") as! ScheduleTableViewController
    let workOrderTabBarItem = generateNavController(vc: scheduleVC, title: "Work Orders", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "baseline_close_white_24pt") )
    let actionTabBarItem = generateEmptyNavController()
    let requestVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Actions", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddRequestSceneIdentifier") as! ActionsViewController
    let requestTabBarItem = generateNavController(vc: requestVC, title: "Request", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "news"))
    let settingsTabBarItem =  generateNavController(vc: MoreSettingsViewController(), title: "More", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "list"))
    
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        image: UIImage(named: "transport"),
        style: .plain,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(buttonTappedAction)
    )

    viewControllers = [homeTabBarItem, workOrderTabBarItem, actionTabBarItem, requestTabBarItem, settingsTabBarItem]//,actionTabBarItem, requestTabBarItem, settingsTabBarItem]
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        middleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
        middleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
        middleButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        middleButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -15),
        ])
    
    //actions
    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture)) //gesture recognizer definicija sho da povikuva koga kje detektira (vo sluchajov swipe)
    swipeDown.direction = .down
    self.slideView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown) // dodavanje na koe view da cheka/detektira (collectionview) i koj gesture swipeDown
}

@objc func buttonTappedAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    print("settings tapped")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(middleButton)
}

fileprivate func generateEmptyNavController() -> UINavigationController {
    let navController = UINavigationController()
    return navController
}

fileprivate func generateNavController(vc: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UINavigationController {
    //vc.navigationItem.title = title
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navController.title = title
    navController.tabBarItem.image = image
    return navController
}
```

}
}

And now on the picture "withoutSettingsButton" it is how its now, and on the picture "withSettingsButton" is how it needs to be, instead the red dot should have a settings icon. Thanks. [withouthSettingsButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdiAM.png)[withSettingsButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPLMj.png)

**are the pictures below

Comment: Please share the code of your ViewController, this little snipped is not enough to spot the issue

Comment: Your code is not clear, And could you please share image of current UI and what you expect to be?

Comment: @AlexGoergisn is this enough ? or do you prefer git link with the full code?

Comment: @Kudos I inserted pisctures

Comment: I added some sample code as an answer. 
In short: you are setting the navigationItem of your UITabBarController which doesn't have any effect in your setup. Instead you have to set it on every view controller that's contained in a navigation controller ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the button as the left or right button of the navigation controller?

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(...)
```

or

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `navigationItem` on **each view controller** that's **contained a navigation controller**.

In your scenario you could do following after setting the viewControllers.

```
...

viewControllers = [homeTabBarItem, workOrderTabBarItem, actionTabBarItem, requestTabBarItem, settingsTabBarItem]//,actionTabBarItem, requestTabBarItem, settingsTabBarItem]

viewControllers?.forEach({ (controller) in
    let viewController = (controller as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController ?? controller
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        image: UIImage(named: "transport"),
        style: .plain,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(self.buttonTappedAction)
    )
})

...
```